# node.js reading file multiple instances

Tags: node.js, io, vlc

my node.js server is going to spawn a child proccess which launches VLC for taking a photo of a video and then send back the photo.

With nginx as a load balancer I'm going to have 4 node.js instances (the number of my server's cores). Is it better to have 4 different video files (one per instance)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are spawning a child process, node isn't technically interactive with the video at all, it is interacting with VLC, which is interacting with the video. So it will spawn four different VLC process.  So really it would be more of a questions if the child process would have any benefit from having it's own video, and you will have as many child processes as you do requests.

From what I understand from the question, this video is probably streaming, and you want to take a still-shot from it, in which case I would take the time as a paramater, and launch the VLC child process like so:

```
C:\VideoLAN\VLC>vlc "path/to/video" --video-filter=scene 
--vout=dummy --start-time=1 --stop-time=5 --scene-ratio=1 
--scene-prefix=img- --scene-path=path/to/image vlc://quit
```

VLC should be able to handle accessing this file multiple times (one per request).

Comment: That's exactly the code I have for VLC ;) In your opinion, do I should  creae four copies of the video or not? Thank you

Comment: It really depends on your hardware set up however I would imagine it wouldn't make much of a difference as I would assume you would run out of memory on most machines before you reach a file i/o wall.

Comment: How can I know if my machine will run out of memory in this case? What's exactly a "file i/o wall"? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: eventually with any program given n requests you will run out of memory, it just depends on how many requests this process can handle.  Your OS has open file limits, you can see them by using: `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`.  In your case what I would do is benchmark the performance to see how many request it can handle.  Build a simple app that runs the test, and then increments the concurrent calls and runs the test again.  This should give you an idea of the resources taken up by each request.  I would also recommend using [Node Time](http://nodetime.com/) to check the profile.  Happy Coding!